# Customer service solution with video conversation and API

Tags: api, video-conferencing

Looking for a customer service solution that can connect a client to a sales representative (ideally it should work also on smart phone for both sales representative and client) so they can initiate a video conversation.

Additional features requested:

- API to be able to integrate this into website.
- Automatic recording of video and audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're into building your own solution for this the [TokBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TokBox) ([platform as a service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service)) could be interesting to you.